# I looking for advice on whether it's better to use a friend or write a getter, but (sort of) break the encapsulation?

Tags: c++

i have a class:

```
template <typename T>
class List {

private:
    struct pointNode {
        T data;
        pointNode* next;
        pointNode* prev;

        pointNode() :data(0), next(nullptr), prev(nullptr) {}
        pointNode(T n_data) : data(n_data), next(nullptr), prev(nullptr) {}

        const T& getValue() {
            return this->data;
        }


    };
    pointNode* head;
    pointNode* tail;

public:

    class Iterator {
        //friend class List;
        using Iterator_type = List<T>::pointNode;
    public:

        Iterator(Iterator_type* rNode) {
            current_node = rNode;
        }

        bool operator !=(const Iterator& pNode) {
            return this->current_node != pNode.current_node;
        }
        T const get_value() {
            return this->current_node->data;
        }

    private:
        Iterator_type* current_node;

    };
    List() : head(nullptr), tail(nullptr) {}
    inline void InsertFront(T&& val);
    inline void InsertBack(T&& val);
    inline bool is_empty();
    inline void Insert_after_v(T&&searchVal,T&&val);
    inline void Insert_after_p(int pos, T&& val);

};
```

I'm trying to write a function that inserts an element after a given:

```
template<typename T>
inline void List<T>::Insert_after(Iterator pos, T&& val)
{
    pointNode* new_node = new pointNode(std::move(val), ... );

}
```

as the 2 parameters of the constructor pointNode,i need to get the value of the iterator

```
 private:
        Iterator_type* current_node;
```

And I think it's the right thing to do ?make a friend:

```
struct pointNode {
  friend class Iterator
```

But I often see that friend is not a particularly good style.

```
class Iterator
{
public:
    Iterator_type* get_current_node() const {
        return current_node;
    }
```

or write something like this :

```
class Iterator
{
public:
    Iterator_type* get_node() const {
        return current_node;
    }
```

But it seems to me that it is not very good to let the user get private data.So maybe who knows how to do the right thing in such situations?I would be grateful for your advice

Comment: Take a look at libstdc++ [implementation](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/forward_list.h) of `std::forward_list`.

Comment: The node, iterator and container form a unit. Encapsulation should happen at that unit's boundary. Internally, you can have much looser access restrictions. Use `friend`.